# tensorflow - tf.data.Dataset randomly skip samples before batching to get different batches

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator

My model consumes chronologically ordered sequences within each input batch. Therefore, i am creating batches before shuffling my input data. This brings the issue that batches always include the same data samples across the whole dataset (starting with the same indices - shifted by `batch_size`), i solved this issue by caching the initial dataset and sampling from skipped datasets, however this eats up memory pretty fast (though my dataset has only 150MB):

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(data)
dataset = dataset.window(size=window_size, shift=window_shift, stride=window_stride, drop_remainder=True).flat_map(lambda x: x.batch(window_size))
dataset = dataset.map(process_fn, num_parallel_calls=8)
dataset = dataset.cache()
datasets = []
for i in range(0, batch_size):
    d = dataset.skip(i)
    d = d.batch(batch_size, drop_remainder=True)
    datasets.append(d)
dataset = tf.data.experimental.sample_from_datasets(datasets)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=30000, reshuffle_each_iteration=False)
dataset = dataset.repeat()
```

Is there another way to achieve this behaviour? I want to cover all possible indices for the start of the first sequence inside a batch.

Comment: Do you find a better way to use less memory?

Comment: Sadly, i did not get to refactor this section of my code yet. I am not sure if there is a better way now.

Comment: I see your set `buffere_size` as 3,000. Have you tried smaller number like 3? Also what `dataset` dimension and shape?

Comment: You should give more code like `process_fn` and `batch_size` so that we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: `batch_size` is 128

Answer (score 0):

You are eating up memory because you are shuffling entire batches -- also skipping may not be very efficient. Since your data seems to be entire in memory, you could possibly sample your data directly in python without too much concern about performance:

```
def make_batch(start_idx):
  batch = np.empty((batch_size, window_size), dtype=data.dtype)
  for batch_idx, data_idx in enumerate(
      range(start_idx, start_idx + window_shift * batch_size, window_shift)):
    batch[batch_idx] = data[data_idx:data_idx + window_size * window_stride:window_stride]
  return batch

dataset = (tf.data.Dataset
  .range(len(data) - window_stride * (window_size - 1) - window_shift * (batch_size- 1))
  .shuffle(buffer_size=30000, reshuffle_each_iteration=False)
  .map(lambda x: tf.py_func(make_batch, [x], tf.float32)) # assuming your data is float32
  .repeat()
  .prefetch(1)) # you might want to consider prefetching for performance
```

The shuffling now occurs on indices, not on entire batches, so it has a much lower memory footprint.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll look into it. Anyway, i hoped for a pure tensorflow solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to create a dataset containing one single element: your original dataset. Then you apply a random skip to that single element dataset and flatten things back to normal using flat_map:

```
dataset_size = 10
max_skip = 5
batch_size = 3

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(dataset_size)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([dataset])
dataset = dataset.flat_map(lambda d: d.skip(tf.random.uniform((), maxval=max_skip, dtype=tf.int64)))
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size, drop_remainder=True)
dataset = dataset.repeat()
dataset = dataset.shuffle(10)
```

Looking at the first five batches gives:

```
for batch in dataset.take(5):
    print(batch.numpy())

[5 6 7]
[1 2 3]
[7 8 9]
[4 5 6]
[3 4 5]
```

Hope that helps.